# Dev c++ errror in the compiler

Tags: c

Hi intelligent people,

I have a problem when I compile this part of a project:

I try to assign an array of structures to another array that is equally declared and the dev c++ tells `"233 H:\PRACTICA 2 25.02\moviment.c incompatible types in assignment"`.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

```
void baixa_enemics(taulell t){
taulell aux;
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<9; j++){
        aux[i][j].ex_enemic = 0;
        printf("%d",aux[i][j].ex_enemic);
    }
printf(" ");
}
printf("wow\n");
for (i=0; i<9; i++){
     for (j=0; j<8; j++){   
        aux[i][j+1]=t[i][j];
        printf("%d",aux[i][j].ex_enemic);
    }
printf(" ");
}
    printf("jia%d", aux[0][1].ex_enemic);
for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
     for (j=0; j<=9; j++){  
(233)           t[i][j]=aux[i]][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Easy: make sure the types you assign are correct! Seriously though, a bit more info about the specific line and types involved will get you a better answer!

Comment: What is taulell? And you´ve a syntax error in line 233 ( too much ] )

Comment: Unless you incorrectly pasted your code, you have an extra `]` in the statement `t[i][j]=aux[i]][j];`

Answer (score 0):

The `taulell aux;` is a single object declaration not an array declaration, which should look something like, for example `taulell aux[10][10];`.

You are also throwing an object as an argument to your function instead of using the pointer or an array.

Good luck.